# Disable JSR-303 annotation processing in springdoc

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

How can I disable JSR-303 annotation processing in springdoc for specific fields?

I have the following request class `MyRequestTO` where the field `name` is actually optional. The `@NotBlank` annotation is only applied to the unwrapped `JsonNullable`. This means the user is allowed to omit the field when sending `MyRequestTO` but if set it must not be blank. However the open api doc marks the `name` field as required. Changing the `@Schema` annotation to `@Schema(type = "string", required = false)` does not help.

I want to avoid a solution where I have to write my own annotation and make use of `org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser`. The desired solution should also work for other types like `JsonNullable<Boolean>` annotated with `@NotNull`.

```java
public class MyRequestTO {

    @Schema(type = "string")
    @NotBlank
    private JsonNullable<String> name = JsonNullable.undefined();

    public JsonNullable<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(JsonNullable<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Relevant dependencies

```
implementation "org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.1"
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.5"
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `format` and `pattern` ?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic in another context, yes. but how can `format` and/or `pattern` solve my problem?

Comment: I thought about your requirement to have the field at least filled with something when not null, and a regex would solve that. But obviously I am not so deeply involved in this special case.

Comment: What if you put the annotation on the generic type parameter (i.e. `private JsonNullable<@NotBlank String> name = JsonNullable.undefined();`)?

Comment: @crizzis works as expected. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@crizzis solution from the comments to my question works as expected. Fields are no longer marked as required but if supplied have to conform to the annotation constraints.

The JSR-303 (e.g. `@NotBlank` or `@NotNull`) annotation belongs in front of the type parameter:

```java
private JsonNullable<@NotBlank String> name = JsonNullable.undefined();
private JsonNullable<@NotNull Boolean> enabled = JsonNullable.undefined();
```

Then the resulting openAPI docs will mark the fields as `"required" : false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working as `@NotBlank` allow null values

The `@NotNull` class isValid() method is called after the `@NotBlank` class isValid(), hence forbidding null values.

So you can try with `@Pattern` with validation of not black string as follows :

```
@Pattern(regexp = "/^$|\\s+/")
String name
```

This will allows not null values but not allow empty string

Comment: Thank you for trying but it is not really what I am looking for. First of all, this suggestion was already made in the comments below my question. Second, I am looking for a way to disable the processing of those annotations. The desired solution should also work for other types like `JsonNullable<Boolean>` annotated with `@NotNull`. Maybe I should have clarified that better.